# Opening CMD in a particular folder in Windows 7

Tags: cmd.exe

I use shift along with "open the command window here". But the issue is that it opens as an administrator `cmd` so my path variables are all screwed up. Could someone tell me how to change this configuration?

Comment: Have you disabled UAC? When I select this the cmd runs with user rights (filtered token).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't supposed to open that as an elevated Administrator's CMD by default. As long as you have UAC (User Account Control) enabled it shouldn't even ask to elevate. Is UAC set to "Default - Notify me only when programs try to make changes to my computer" ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have uac enabled...

Another thing to check is go to the cmd.exe file, right-click, properties, advanced and make sure "run as administrator" is not checked.